# log4j and MulticolorLayout print signs instead of colors

Tags: log4j

In order to print log messages in different colors according to log severity, I'm using log4j and MulticolorLayout.
The problem is that i am getting strange signs instead of colors both on the console log and on the file log.

For example-

```
[[0;37mINFO [m] hereIsTheLogMessage
```

using jcabi version 0.12, windows, Kepler, java 7

Any advice?

Thanks,
Shirley.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a file you can't get any colors, only this meta symbols. That's logical. Why don't you see colors in console - that's a question. I think the problem is with your terminal. It just doesn't emulate UNIX terminals correctly.